# likelihood of an exponential family

Tags: probability, statistics

I am starting a course in statistics by myself. I am a biologist but currently I am taking this course in order to comprehend in a better way the statistics behind in the biostatistics field.

I am starting to read the log-likelihood topic. There is and example in the lecture notes that I downloaded from the internet where they say that it is evident that for the canonical form of the exponential families for some scalar functions $b(\cdot)$ and $c(\cdot)$ and parameter $\theta$ has a density (or mass function)
of the form:

$$f(y|\theta) = exp\{y\theta - b(\theta) + c(y)\} $$

the log-likelihood for this model (up to a constant) can be written in the form:

$$\ell(\beta|y) = y^T X \beta - 1^T b(X\beta) $$

where $1$ is an $n$-dimensional vector of $1$s, $T$ denotes transpose, and the function $b()$ is “vectorised”.

So, if you take the log of the canonical function you get:

$$\ell(f(y|\theta)) = y\theta - b(\theta) + c(y) $$

but then should I parameterise the $f(y|\theta)$ in order to get the form that they mentioned?

Thank you very much for your help and time. Happy new year everyone.

Comment: This is somehow like a Generalized Linear Model. In the elementary setting, we have an unknown parameter $\theta$ (can be vector) to be estimated. The distribution of the observed random variable $Y$ will depends on $\theta$, described by the likelihood function. In a linear (regression) model setting, we have the extra independent random variable(s) $X$ which interact with the parameter $\beta$ linearly as $X\beta$